# Docker network macvlan, las subinterfaces no reciben contestación de arp

Tags: docker, networking

Les cuento mi problema

tengo varios contenedores en docker con ip del estilo 192.168.X.2/24 de forma que cada contenedor esté en una subred distinta. Estas redes están creadas de la siguiente forma

```
docker network create -d macvlan   --subnet=192.168.4.0/24   --gateway=192.168.4.1   -o parent=eth0.4 test3
```

Estas maquinas están en un Centos7 en una maquina virtual con virtualbox y adaptador puente y la interfaz de red conectado a un router cisco de forma que ,de momento, todas estas redes tienen sus gateways en el puerto 1 como ips en la vlan1 como secondary

La idea es montar algo similar a esto pero con disntintas ip de vlans
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#macvlan-8021q-trunk-bridge-mode-example-usage

EL problema es que las consultas arp de estas subinterfaces no reciben respuesta

```html
08:00:41.132782 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:42.135804 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:42.138763 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8001.1c:17:d3:0d:d4:80.8001, length 43
08:00:43.138921 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:44.143655 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8001.1c:17:d3:0d:d4:80.8001, length 43
08:00:45.134850 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:46.136855 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:46.151921 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8001.1c:17:d3:0d:d4:80.8001, length 43
08:00:47.138610 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
08:00:48.153870 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8001.1c:17:d3:0d:d4:80.8001, length 43
08:00:48.521751 IP 192.168.50.2.64007 > 192.168.110.102.snmp:  GetRequest(62)  25.3.2.1.5.1 25.3.5.1.1.1 25.3.5.1.2.1
08:00:49.138713 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.1 tell 192.168.2.2, length 28
```

en cambio responde a ping desde la maquina virtual a las interfaces del router por lo que el fallo debe de estar en la dirección de arp.

probé a modificar el proxy_arp en las interfaces con

```html
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp_pvlan 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_filter
```

alguna ayuda ?

Comment: vale ya funciona se arregló cambiando las interfaces, cree interfaces macvlan enganchadas a las eth1.XXX en modo bridge y luego una ip rotua a cada contenedor